# Finite extensions of the $p$-adic numbers which are neither unramified nor totally ramified

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime and consider the field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ of $p$-adic numbers.

**Question:** What is an example for a finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$ which is neither unramified nor totally ramified? In case you know an explicit example, I am also curious to learn how to find the inertia degree, the ramification index and the maximal ideal of the valuation ring.

A general problem for me is that I am absolutely not able to find any literature containing some instructive examples and calculations in finite extensions $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, In case you know a good reference, this would be very helpful to me. Thanks!

Comment: For question 1, can't you just take the composite of something unramified and something totally ramified?

Comment: More concretely, take $F \vert \mathbb Q_p$ any proper unramified extension, and then let $K := F(\sqrt[n] p)$ for any $n \ge 2$.

Comment: There is a general theorem which says that for a finite extension K''/K of local  fields , with residual extension k"/k , the  unramified sub-extensions K'/K of K"/K correspond bijectively to the sub-extensions k'/k of k''/k which are separable. It follows immediately that K"/K contains a maximal unramified sub-extension K'/K, which corresponds to the maximal separable sub-extension of k"/k. Thus K"/K' is totally ramified. See Serre, "Local Fiels", section II 5, coroll. 2. The correspondence is explained in detail in the proof of the theorem.

Comment: Complement in the case of the base field Q_p : Its residual field being F_p, all the separable extensions of F_p are obtained by adding to F_p a primitive (p^n - 1)-th root of 1 in a separable closure of F_p.  The cited thm. then implies that the maximal unramified subextension F_ur of F/Q_p is obtained by adding to Q_p a root of 1 of order prime to p in an algebraic  closure of Q_p. Then construct any totally ramified extension of F_ur, e.g. by adding a root of an Eisenstein polynomial.